# Thread.Join stops a threads exit (or appears too) but SpinWaiting for the thread to exit doesnt

Tags: c#, multithreading

We had a problem of some functions that need to be run against an API periodically to get information from a device and the solution I came up with uses a new object to run the thread and the object has some functions to tell the thread to terminate. The object needs to do some setup, run a periodic command and handle shutting down. It also needs to be able to run other commands interleaved with the periodic command. It has three functions that it needs when being setup (Startup, Shutdown and Periodic) and you can pass in a delegate to the command you want interleaved. The startup and periodic command, and the interleaved command, work well enough.

The problem is when trying to stop operation and terminate the thread.

The thread function that executes looks like

```
    private void InterleaverThread()
    {
        if (this.StartupFunction != null)
        {
            this.StartupFunction();
        }

        this.startUpFinished = true;

        while (!this.stop)
        {
            if (this.optCmd != null)
            {
                this.optCmdResult = this.optCmd();
                this.optCmdFinished = true;
            }

            if (this.stop)
            {
                break;
            }

            this.lastPeriodicCmdResult = this.PeriodicFunction();
        }

        if (this.ShutdownFunction != null)
        {
            this.ShutdownFunction();
        }

        this.startUpFinished = false;
    }
```

and the Stop command looks like

```
    public void StopInterleaver()
    {
        if (!this.IsRunning())
        {
            return;
        }

        this.stop = true;

        this.interleaverThread.Join();
        // SpinWait.SpinUntil(this.IsRunning);
    }
```

When the Thread.Join() command is used the thread never returns but if I used the `SpinWait.SpinUntil()` the `StopInterleaver` command returns in the time frame expected. The `IsRunning()` command just checks the thread `IsAlive`.

```
    public bool IsRunning()
    {
        if (this.interleaverThread == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return this.interleaverThread.IsAlive;
    }
```

The `Thread` is from `System.Threading`.

We can't figure out why `.Join()` doesn't return but `SpinWait.WaitUntil` does. It seems like they should be doing essentially the same thing.

Comment: Well, `SpinUntil(this.IsRunning)` is going to return immediately, assuming that `IsRunning` returns `true`.

Comment: Ahh good point, that is obviously a bug on my part. I changed it to `SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => !this.IsRunning());` and the problem is back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suspect that the compiler is optimizing your loop and not actually checking the `stop` flag. That is, you have:

```
while (!this.stop)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Since the compiler sees that the value of `stop` can't change inside the function, it can just cache the value in a register.

One way to check if that's a problem is to mark the `stop` variable [volatile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx), as in:

```
private volatile bool stop;
```

That's not a particularly robust way to do it, though. The typical way to handle things is with a `CancellationToken`. See [Cancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd997364(v=vs.100).aspx).

For a more detailed look at cancellation and an example, see [Polling for Cancellation](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/05/07/polling-for-cancellation/).